# How can i open up a new activity from cardview with my current build

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, cardview

If I should change it from card to maybe a button for easier code please let me know, but I have tried multiple ways with card view and none seem to be working for  me. Im trying to open a new activity when i click the cardview for DashboardTmsActivity.

current error is this

```
MainActivity.kt
Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function':19
Unresolved reference: activity
Unresolved reference: activity:23
```

here is my current code.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.cameron.armymaintenance

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import com.cameron.armymaintenance.databinding.ActivityDashboardTmsBinding
import com.cameron.armymaintenance.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : DrawerBaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

            view.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.card1).setOnClickListener {
                val card1 = Intent(activity, ActivityDashboardTmsBinding::class.java)
                activity?.startActivity(card1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DrawerBaseActivity.kt

```
package com.cameron.armymaintenance

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

open class DrawerBaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout? = null

    override fun setContentView(view: View?) {
        drawerLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer_base, null) as DrawerLayout
        val container = drawerLayout!!.findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.activityContainer)
        container.addView(view)
        super.setContentView(drawerLayout)
        val toolbar = drawerLayout!!.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolBar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val navigationView = drawerLayout!!.findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.menu_drawer_open,
            R.string.menu_drawer_open
        )
        drawerLayout!!.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    private fun allocateActivityTitle(titleString: String?) {
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar!!.title = titleString
        }
    }

    open fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}
}
```

DashboardTmsActivity.kt

```
package com.cameron.armymaintenance

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class DashboardTmsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard_tms)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there should be 2 errors if I have not misinterpreted:

```
Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function':19
Unresolved reference: activity:23
```

1. `onViewCreated()` should not be placed inside `onCreate()`. If you need to implement `onViewCreated()`, it should be at the same level with `onCreate()`
2. `activity` is not available in an `Activity`. It only exists in a `Fragment` class. You can simply use `this` in an `Activity`.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : DrawerBaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
    
    // Move to same level for function
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        view.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.card1).setOnClickListener {
            // Use this in Activity
            val card1 = Intent(this@MainActivity, ActivityDashboardTmsBinding::class.java)
            startActivity(card1)
        }
    }
}
```